Y parameters for a two-port network (basic engineering circuit analysis)
Can anyone explain to me why I2 is 0 in the system of equations?
I got the short-circuit admittance parameters. However, once the current source and load show up in the network, it is unclear why I2 in the second equation goes to 0. Perhaps there is an assumption I am not making.



Please provide an attempt at a solution

@VoltageSpike I think Raquel has provided the complete solution. There's nothing to add. It's correct and complete. The question is why is there a zero in the circled set of equations and in the right side bracketed currents in matrix form. There's a good answer to that question. But I cannot imagine how Raquel could add anything to this since the presentation given is exactly what's needed to ask the why question being asked.

Thats coming out of a text, usually texts do not provide the solution.

@Raquel Can you provide the source for the image, it probably has a copyright if it's coming out of a book.

The short answer, Raquel, is that there is an injected current for the V1 node, which is totally independent of the node voltage. So a 2 appears there. But there is no injected current that is independent of the voltage of the V2 node. So a 0 appears there. If that's not sufficient, I can write more about it. But that's the short explanation. (There is also a coincidence in this case that the injected current for the V1 node just happens to point in the same direction as the I1 arrow and is in series with that wire segment.)

The parameters of the equivalent quadripoles are dynamic parameters, that is, they consider temporal variations of the variable physical quantities of the system, i.e. currents and voltages. We can consider infinitesimal variations and therefore the differentials of the variables or the finite variations by writing them with the delta. For simplicity, the delta is omitted so:

